# Why is tex4ht not installing?

Tags: texlive, tex4ht, texlive-2023

I've installed TeX Live, but was told that there was an error installing tex4ht, and to run `tlmgr update --all --reinstall-forcibly-removed` to fix it. I did so, but got this:

```
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl: saving backups to C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/backups
[1/2, ??:??/??:??] auto-install: cabin (65358) [3053k] ... TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\a5svVCGkT5\YMY0U97iaF/cabin.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=8227929382396ece0ddac74095387ee0c96d2102fffe5121f89182836792933a6ad66ded538229c5bd12f65fe7518d00a333835c17537761f309db578e81bd3b, arg=5d96c971e8924402048edc533cdc048398fe4bcfcaed87bd0709511056f94d68ba9785599363e59c9e26fcb7bc724bb9481f8e5ea14ef8cef07376922083ceb2
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2619: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1985: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1820: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1736: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:3502: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:798: main::action_update
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:704: main::execute_action
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:367: main::main
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\a5svVCGkT5\YMY0U97iaF/cabin.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\DJclAE5Vak
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/cabin.tar.xz
tlmgr.pl: couldn't install new package cabin
[2/2, 00:02/00:03] auto-install: tex4ht (68346) [2634k] ... TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: checksums differ for C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\a5svVCGkT5\UPrLINfDk0/tex4ht.tar.xz:
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   tlchecksum=a096a2990b70b9f2649edca567ba87a3e2b8e981609ebd5ebab724b2a74e3759ca63c1fde8221600b01d18ee85e8e35a7e7325c22df87faa480d80840a9bb7e0, arg=a52ff06f71eaa3e551a8d682bfd9d1dfac76e3386f564a9bebe0fa63a3bc098d36ed333168b4d4a1feff25f1132c68626394b4bc41bf4f8dfd562f82a06e63d4
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove: backtrace:
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm:2619: TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1985: TeXLive::TLUtils::unpack
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1820: TeXLive::TLPDB::_install_data
 -> C:/texlive/2023/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm:1736: TeXLive::TLPDB::not_virtual_install_package
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:3502: TeXLive::TLPDB::install_package
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:798: main::action_update
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:704: main::execute_action
 -> C:\texlive\2023\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\tlmgr.pl:367: main::main
TeXLive::TLUtils::check_file_and_remove:   removing C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\a5svVCGkT5\UPrLINfDk0/tex4ht.tar.xz, but saving copy in C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\W7cfPCDa5G
TLPDB::_install_data: downloading did not succeed (check_file_and_remove failed) for https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/archive/tex4ht.tar.xz
tlmgr.pl: couldn't install new package tex4ht
```

I have no idea what I'm doing. The last time I installed a TeX editor, it didn't require a separate TeX install, take 6 hours, or have random package install errors. Please help. Do I need to just give up with trying to get TeX Live working and try to figure out what software I had installed years ago that worked?